# Увеличить скорость обработки файлов на Apache Tike

Tags: java, файлы, apache, сервер, maven

В разработке проект на maven в NetBeans. Хочу написать сервер обработки файлов, пока тестирую под Windows.
В сервере использую библиотеку Apache Tika.

При обработке 133 файлов ( общий размер где-то 133 МБ) смог добиться скорости обработки:
133 МБ / 33 сек, что составляет 4 МБ/сек. Хотелось бы достичь скорости в 37,2 МБ/сек.

Вот код:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.stack1;

import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String outdir = "C:\\java\\Output\\"; //Path[1] - выходной путь из config.xml        
        FileFilter filter = (File d) -> d.getName().endsWith("psp"); // конец Filter
        Stream.of(new File("C:\\java\\Input").listFiles(filter)).parallel()
                .forEach(file -> {
                    String srcFileName = replaceExt(file.getAbsolutePath(), ".dat");
                    String targetFileName = outdir + replaceExt(file.getName(), ".txt");
            try {
                new Task(srcFileName, targetFileName).run();
            } catch (SAXException | TikaException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Parser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
                });
    }
    
    private static String replaceExt(String fileName, String ext) {
        return fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.')) + ext;
    }

    private static class Task {

        private final String srcFileName;
        private final String targetFileName;
        
        private final Metadata metadata;
        private final Tika tika;

        private Task(String srcFileName, String targetFileName) {
            this.srcFileName = srcFileName;
            this.targetFileName = targetFileName;
            this.metadata = new Metadata();
            this.tika = new Tika();            
        }

        public void run() throws SAXException, TikaException {//throws Exception {
            
            try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(srcFileName))) {
                String mimeType = tika.detect(srcFileName); //определяем mimeType нашего документа
                metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);//устанавливаем mimeType
                AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();//create универсальный парсер который на основе mimeType  принимает решение какой использовать узкоспециализированный парсер
                ParseContext pc = new ParseContext(); //create xml-парсер
                ContentHandler ch = new BodyContentHandler(-1);//здесь будет содержаться тело документа в виде plan text
                parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc); //разбор файла на части
                Files.write(Paths.get(targetFileName), ch.toString().getBytes());
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

и pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myThreadPool</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <tika>1.2</tika>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.Tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>Tika-serialization</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>     
            <groupId>org.apache.Tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
            <version>1.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.compendium</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>biz.aQute</groupId>
            <artifactId>bndlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.50.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-debugger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ome</groupId>
            <artifactId>bio-formats</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>preflight</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Helper's dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gagravarr</groupId>
            <artifactId>vorbis-java-tika</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
            <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
               
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                       <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                       <mainClass>com.mycompany.mythreadpool.myThread</mainClass>
                       
                       <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                   <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                      
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                       <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.mycompany.mythreadpool.myThread</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
            
            


 
        
        
        
        
        </plugins>
    
    </build>

</project>
```

Вот кол-во памяти ( в битах):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал такой запуск программы через консоль:

```
java -jar -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xss1024k D:\Programs\Qt\Units\MyJavaProjects\myThreadPool\target\myThreadPool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Сборка прошла успешно, но при выполнении выводиться такая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Arrays.stream(Arrays.java:5004)
    at java.util.stream.Stream.of(Stream.java:1000)
    at com.mycompany.stack1.Parser.main(Parser.java:33)
Command execution failed.
```

Все равно такая же скорость. Подскажите как можно увеличить скорость обработки файлов? Может есть какие-то стоящие мысли как можно все исправить, заранее спасибо.

Comment: это нужно срочно рефакторить. слишком много лишнего, в таком виде оптимизировать будет сложно

Comment: Ну а например, что именно может оказаться лишним?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала сделаем так:

```
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.ContentHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Parser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String outdir = "C:\\java\\Output\\"; //Path[1] - выходной путь из config.xml        
        FileFilter filter = (File d) -> d.getName().endsWith("psp"); // конец Filter
        Stream.of(new File("C:\\java").listFiles(filter)).parallel()
                .forEach(file -> {
                    String srcFileName = replaceExt(file.getAbsolutePath(), ".dat");
                    String targetFileName = outdir + replaceExt(file.getName(), ".txt");
                    new Task(srcFileName, targetFileName).run();
                });
    }
    
    private static String replaceExt(String fileName, String ext) {
        return fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.')) + ext;
    }

    private static class Task {

        private final String srcFileName;
        private final String targetFileName;
        
        private final Metadata metadata;
        private final Tika tika;

        private Task(String srcFileName, String targetFileName) {
            this.srcFileName = srcFileName;
            this.targetFileName = targetFileName;
            this.metadata = new Metadata();
            this.tika = new Tika();            
        }

        public void run() {//throws Exception {
            
            try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(srcFileName))) {
                String mimeType = tika.detect(srcFileName); //определяем mimeType нашего документа
                metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);//устанавливаем mimeType
                AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();//create универсальный парсер который на основе mimeType  принимает решение какой использовать узкоспециализированный парсер
                ParseContext pc = new ParseContext(); //create xml-парсер
                ContentHandler ch = new BodyContentHandler(-1);//здесь будет содержаться тело документа в виде plan text
                parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc); //разбор файла на части
                Files.write(Paths.get(targetFileName), ch.toString().getBytes());
            } 
            catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Теперь код стал короче, его проще понять и внести изменения, но поскольку тесты нам не завезли, дебажить придется вам...

Я избавился от вывода в консоль как от очень медленной операции, к тому же в многопоточном режиме от нее толку не много (выводится непонятно когда и откуда).

Я добавил паралельный стрим вместо тредов, поскольку любой поток ввода-вывода - исчерпаемый ресурс, он может закончится. это надо тестить.

Поток ввода-вывода - довольно дорогой с точки зрения производительности, посему : 1)не стоит открывать его лишний раз, 2)закрытие лучше возложить на try with resources, 3)всегда буферизируйте его.

Создание экземпляров классов (особенно с нетривиальной инициализацией), занимает ресурсы и время, посему нужно рассмотреть возможность использования синглтонов (если, разумеется, это возможно в многопоточной среде) для таких классов как AutoDetectParser, ParseContext и.т.д

Персмотрите и оптимизируйте использование класса File. Обращение к файловой системе - далеко не бесплатное с точки зрения системных ресурсов, а вы создаете его экземпляры на каждом шагу. Возможно , есть есть способ получить, к примеру путь к файлу, либо его урл и работать с ним, не запрашивая эти  даннык каждый раз у класса File.

Уберите хардкод! Принимайте все параметры в метод, либо в конструктор, вот это String outdir = "D:\java\Output" и это String newName = outdir + "/" + pspFile.replace("dat", "txt"); по факту статическая информация. String  - ссылочный тип, так зачем тогда создавать это в каждом потоке для каждого файла? Хардкод - зло

Comment: Попробовал выполнить этот код, выводиться такая ошибка: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed.

Код идет на строчку: try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(newStr))) {.

Потом сюда:               
 String mimeType = tika.detect(is);.
Но после нее опять переходить на ту строчку (которая выше, то что с try).

Совсем нет мыслей как отдебажить это, может у вас есть какие мысли?

Comment: @это как раз не так сложно. во-первых, в методе мейн замените стрим на чтение одного файла (нам не нужен многопоточный треш при дебаге). во-вторых, ваша ошибка с высокой вероятностью связана с тем, что стрим передается в метод детект, после чего закрывается, но у метода детект есть перегруженный метод, принимающий стринг, посему попробуйте так String mimeType = tika.detect(newStr); в-третьих, дебагер никто не отменял. но самый главный вопрос, почему вы на сервере читаете из ресурсов - getResourceAsStream? где лежат ваши файлы? кроме того, я не понимаю магии с подстановкий расширений файлов.

Comment: @Evendie вообще, что означает "обработка файлов"? в чем ее смысл? непонятна задача, поэтому сложно найти решение.

Comment: Задача: взять файл и достать его содержимое и метаданные, файл может быть разного формата, насколько я знаю Tika неплохой вариант для такой работы. Почему использую "getResourceAsStream", подобное позаимствовал с сайтов, у вас есть идея чем можно это заменить?

Comment: заменить на InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(newStr)). чтение из ресурсов вам нужно в том случае , когда вы читаете из папки ресурсов в вашем проекте. все дело в том, что после компиляции вы получите jar, а это по факту архив, и ваша папка ресурсов окажется внутри архива, еще и изменив свой путь. вот тогда используется  getResourceAsStream.

Comment: мне непонятно, как это работает. вы берете файл, подменяете имя и заталкиваете в инпутстрим. String newStr = file.getAbsolutePath().replace("psp", "dat"), пытаясь прочитать файл с измененным именем. закономерно такого файла не существует и мы получим ошибку.

Comment: Во входной папке есть 2 типа файлов: file.psp и file.dat. Логика такая: если у нас есть psp файл, то на основе его мы ищем файл dat, путем такой замены replace("psp", "dat"). Сами имена одинаковые и мы изменяем расширение. А как вы думаете, как бы вы сделали, вместо этого подхода?

Comment: @Evendie теперь немного понятнее конечная цель... Код исправил и еще больше упростил. Проверьте как это работает и заодно возможность использовать синглтоны (то, о чем я писал выше)

Comment: Попробовал запустить, NetBeans подправил какие-то моменты, добавив исключения. Собрал проект maven'ом, но при запуске выводиться ошибка, как думаете как ее можно исправить?

(Свой код, который запускаю написал его выше, и сообщение об ошибке тоже выше)

(Подскажите есть ли возможность пообщаться с вами еще где-то? Было бы интересно перенять хоть какую-то часть вашего опыта, заранее большое спасибо)

Comment: Все изменения структуры безусловно полезны и действительно делают код более поддерживаемым. Только тут совсем нет ответа на главный вопрос: "как добиться ускорения почти в 10 раз?". Есть сомнения, что эти, по сути косметические, изменения дадут прирост даже в 2 раза.

Comment: @Roman Konoval а почему именно в 10? давайте добьемся в 1_000_000. это же лучше! в идеале использовать при этом пентиум 1, он ничего не стоит, не что тредрипер. и вообще научно-технический прогресс больше не нужен, все будем ускорять бесконечно. вы вообще сейчас о чем?

Comment: @Evendie теперь нужно понять причину ошибки и исключить возможность ошибок, связанных с тем, что наши потоки ввода-вывода (которые являются исчерпаемым ресурсом) используются в многопоточной среде. для этого уберите вызов .parallel(), мы получим один поток для того, чтобы отдебажить код и убрать ошибки , не связанные с многопоточностью. если вы по прежнему продолжите получать ошибку (используя 1 поток), нужен ее стектрейс, чтобы понять причину

Comment: @Дмитрий я о том, что автора вопроса не устраивает скорость в 4 МБ/сек и он хочет достичь 37МБ/c и это основная проблема.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, почему желание достичь такой скорости ( перейти с 4МБ за сек, на 37МБ за сек) это главная проблема?

Comment: "Главная проблема" в том смысле, что это является сутью вопроса. Вопрос ведь в том, как увеличить скорость обработки. А этот ответ в плане увеличения скорости обработки мало что дает. Если бы вопрос звучал, как улучшить структуру кода - то тогда другое дело.